# Why do my JButtons not appear until the applet is resize and my JCombo boxes are invisible until clicked on?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, applet, awt

Hi first off I'd like to say I am new to the site and pretty new to programming (mainly with graphics) and I'd like to apologize in advance for asking any stupid questions. Also I'd like to thank anyone kind enough to take time out of their day to help me with this.

My problem is that when I try to make menus by having certain JButtons make certain buttons not visible then other ones visible (to make it look like a different screen) everything goes invisible unless i re-size the window or minimize. However after doing this once the switching from menu to menu works perfectly. Also I have some JComboBoxes that appear but are either invisible or partially invisible until they are clicked on and I don't know why they are doing that either.

This applet is going to be put online when done as a tool to help other kids with chemistry the part I started working on first (the part with the JComboBoxes) is a unit converter. I wanted to get everything working before placing everything correctly position wise and some of my variable names may be a bit confusing to others so if describing what something is supposed to do in my code would make it easier for you to help please just ask and I will try my best to explain what I am doing there.

Thanks again

Here is my code for creating the graphics for the applet:

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.applet.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class test extends Applet implements ActionListener 
{
 private int screen = -1;//-1 is value for startup screen
 private JComboBox box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, box11, box22, box33, box44,          box55;//drop downs for unit converter
 private static String[] cVolumeO = {"Ml","L"}; //Unit options for converter
 private static String[] cAreaO = {"sqFt","sqMile"};
 private static String[] cLengthO = {"ft","Mile"};
 private static String[] cTempO = {"C","F","K"};
 private static String[] cChemO = {"Moles","Grams"}; //end of unit options for converter
 private static String[] filename;//store pic filenames
 private Icon[] pics;//stores applet pics
 private JLabel picture;
 private Button MainMenu;
 private Button periodicTable, element, solvers, balancer, fChart, converter; //main menu buttons
 private Button Continue; //start up screen
 private TextField dialog;
 private TextField cVolume, cArea, cLength, cTemp, cChem; //converter entry fields
 private TextField volumeAnswer, areaAnswer, lengthAnswer, tempAnswer, chemAnswer;//converter answer fields

 public void init(){  
      setBackground(new Color(10,10,205));
      setSize(500, 500);
      setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

      instanceVarAssigner();//sets all variables to their correct values (it's basically a constructor)
      createStartScreen_();//sets up default screen by making all invisible except continue button + default words and picture
      assignLocation();//positions all of the items to their proper locations

      add(Continue); //adds all buttons to the applet screen
      add(periodicTable);
      add(element);
      add(solvers);
      add(balancer);
      add(fChart);
      add(converter); 
      add(MainMenu);
      add(box1);
      add(box11);
      add(box2);
      add(box22);
      add(box3);
      add(box33);
      add(box4);
      add(box44);
      add(box5);
      add(box55);
      add(cVolume);
      add(cArea);
      add(cLength);
      add(cTemp);
      add(cChem);
      add(volumeAnswer);
      add(areaAnswer);
      add(lengthAnswer);
      add(tempAnswer);
      add(chemAnswer);

      // adds functionality to all the buttons
      periodicTable.addActionListener(this); 
      element.addActionListener(this); 
      solvers.addActionListener(this); 
      balancer.addActionListener(this); 
      fChart.addActionListener(this); 
      converter.addActionListener(this); 
      MainMenu.addActionListener(this);
      Continue.addActionListener(this);
      box1.addActionListener(this);
      box2.addActionListener(this);
      box3.addActionListener(this);
      box4.addActionListener(this);
      box5.addActionListener(this);

      repaint();     
 }//end init();


    public void paint(Graphics g) 
     { 
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.drawString(dialog.getText(),20,100);

      if(screen==0){//Main Menu
          mainSetup();
      }
      else if(screen==1){//PeriodicTable
          ptSetup();
      }
      else if(screen==2){//Element Finder/Info
          elementSetup();
      }
      else if(screen==3){//Solvers
          solverSetup();
      }
      else if(screen==4){//Balancer
          balancerSetup();
      }
      else if(screen==5){//fChart
          fChartSetup();
      }
      else if(screen==6){//Converter
          converterSetup();
      }

 }//end paint();


    private void solverSetup() {
        periodicTable.setVisible(false);
        element.setVisible(false);
        solvers.setVisible(false);
        balancer.setVisible(false);
        fChart.setVisible(false);
        converter.setVisible(false);
        MainMenu.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void elementSetup() {
      periodicTable.setVisible(false);
      element.setVisible(false);
      solvers.setVisible(false);
      balancer.setVisible(false);
      fChart.setVisible(false);
      converter.setVisible(false);
      MainMenu.setVisible(true);    
    }

    private void balancerSetup() {
      periodicTable.setVisible(false);
      element.setVisible(false);
      solvers.setVisible(false);
      balancer.setVisible(false);
      fChart.setVisible(false);
      converter.setVisible(false);
      MainMenu.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void fChartSetup() {
      periodicTable.setVisible(false);
      element.setVisible(false);
      solvers.setVisible(false);
      balancer.setVisible(false);
      fChart.setVisible(false);
      converter.setVisible(false);
      MainMenu.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void converterSetup() {
    periodicTable.setVisible(false);
    element.setVisible(false);
    solvers.setVisible(false);
    balancer.setVisible(false);
    fChart.setVisible(false);
    converter.setVisible(false);
    MainMenu.setVisible(true);
    box1.setVisible(true);
    box2.setVisible(true);
    box3.setVisible(true);
    box4.setVisible(true);
    box5.setVisible(true);
    box11.setVisible(true);
    box22.setVisible(true);
    box33.setVisible(true);
    box44.setVisible(true);
    box55.setVisible(true);
    cVolume.setVisible(true);
    cArea.setVisible(true);
    cLength.setVisible(true);
    cTemp.setVisible(true);
    cChem.setVisible(true);
    volumeAnswer.setVisible(true);
    areaAnswer.setVisible(true);
    lengthAnswer.setVisible(true);
    tempAnswer.setVisible(true);
    chemAnswer.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void ptSetup() {
      periodicTable.setVisible(false);
      element.setVisible(false);
      solvers.setVisible(false);
      balancer.setVisible(false);
      fChart.setVisible(false);
      converter.setVisible(false);
      MainMenu.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void mainSetup() {
      periodicTable.setVisible(true);
      element.setVisible(true);
      solvers.setVisible(true);
      balancer.setVisible(true);
      fChart.setVisible(true);
      converter.setVisible(true);
      MainMenu.setVisible(false);   
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)  
     { 
         if(evt.getSource() == element){ 
            dialog.setText("element was pushed.");
            screen=2;
            repaint();
         }

         else if(evt.getSource() == periodicTable){
            dialog.setText("pt was pushed.");
            screen=1;
            repaint(); 
         }

         else if(evt.getSource() == solvers){
            dialog.setText("s was pushed.");
            screen=3;
            repaint(); 
         }

         else if(evt.getSource() == balancer){
            dialog.setText("b was pushed.");
            screen=4;
            repaint(); 
         }

         else if(evt.getSource() == fChart){
            dialog.setText("fC was pushed.");
            screen=5;
            repaint(); 
         }

         else if(evt.getSource() == converter){
            dialog.setText("c was pushed.");
            screen=6;
            repaint(); 
         }

         else if(evt.getSource() == MainMenu){
            createStartScreen_();//refreshes shutting off of all things so that the code doesnt need to be repeated.
            dialog.setText("Main Menu");
            Continue.setVisible(false);
            screen=0;
            repaint();
         }

         else if(evt.getSource() == Continue){
             dialog.setText("Main Menu");
             screen=0;
             Continue.setVisible(false);
             repaint();  
         }
      }//end actionPreformed();

    private void instanceVarAssigner(){
        MainMenu=new Button("Main Menu");
          periodicTable = new Button("Peoridic Table"); 
          element = new Button("Element Finder/Info");
          solvers = new Button("Solvers"); 
          balancer = new Button("Equation Balancer"); 
          fChart = new Button("Formula Chart"); 
          converter = new Button("Unit Converter"); 
          Continue = new Button("Continue");

          box1 = new JComboBox(cVolumeO);//converter items
          box11 = new JComboBox(cVolumeO);
          box2 = new JComboBox(cAreaO);
          box22 = new JComboBox(cAreaO);
          box3 = new JComboBox(cLengthO);
          box33 = new JComboBox(cLengthO);
          box4 = new JComboBox(cTempO);
          box44 = new JComboBox(cTempO);
          box5 = new JComboBox(cChemO);
          box55 = new JComboBox(cChemO);
          volumeAnswer = new TextField("0");
          areaAnswer = new TextField("0");
          lengthAnswer = new TextField("0");
          tempAnswer = new TextField("0");
          chemAnswer = new TextField("0");
          cVolume = new TextField("0");
          cArea = new TextField("0");
          cLength = new TextField("0");
          cTemp = new TextField("0");
          cChem = new TextField("0"); //end of converter items

          dialog = new TextField("Homework Helper: Chemistry Edition V1.0 by BMCA Tech. Press Continue to begin...",35);

          preventChanges();//makes all answer fields in app uneditable
    }

    private void createStartScreen_(){//sets all buttons to false other than continue which is set to true and displays default pic and text.
        Continue.setVisible(true);
        dialog.setText("Homework Helper: Chemistry Edition V1.0 by BMCA Tech. Press Continue to begin...");
        periodicTable.setVisible(false);
        MainMenu.setVisible(false);
        converter.setVisible(false);
        fChart.setVisible(false);
        balancer.setVisible(false);
        solvers.setVisible(false);
        element.setVisible(false);
        box1.setVisible(false);
        box2.setVisible(false);
        box3.setVisible(false);
        box4.setVisible(false);
        box5.setVisible(false);
        box11.setVisible(false);
        box22.setVisible(false);
        box33.setVisible(false);
        box44.setVisible(false);
        box55.setVisible(false);
        cVolume.setVisible(false);
        cArea.setVisible(false);
        cLength.setVisible(false);
        cTemp.setVisible(false);
        cChem.setVisible(false);
        volumeAnswer.setVisible(false);
        areaAnswer.setVisible(false);
        lengthAnswer.setVisible(false);
        tempAnswer.setVisible(false);
        chemAnswer.setVisible(false);
    }//end createStartScreen

    private void assignLocation(){
        MainMenu.setLocation(10, 10);
        box1.setLocation(10, 50);
    }

    private void preventChanges(){
        volumeAnswer.setEditable(false);
        areaAnswer.setEditable(false);
        lengthAnswer.setEditable(false);
        tempAnswer.setEditable(false);
        chemAnswer.setEditable(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) **Don't mix Swing and AWT components together.**  Use all Swing components 2) Please don't post over 300 lines of code (with a slew of compilation errors) and claim the problem is at run-time.  Try to reproduce the problem with ***one*** combo-box and button. 3) Don't try to resize an applet from within code. 4) Call `validate()` after adding all components.

Comment: Uggh.. ignore the comment about compilation errors, problem is this end.

Comment: Use a `CardLayout` for swapping between the different GUI elements.  That will probably solve the problem.  If not, post a ***much*** shorter code example that has just two cards, each with one component.

Comment: @Andrew I switched all to Swing and added `Validate()` which fixed the problems mostly. I will probably end up using `CardLayout` in the end but I need to read into it more to learn it. The only question I have left is why in the following example I still have the problem where the buttons are invisible until the cursor goes over them. Sorry about the 300 lines didn't think that through and should have made a smaller example like you said. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Sorry I am new to the website and I can't figure out how to add the example I have that problem with the format correctly in the comment. Its much smaller only 46 lines

Comment: *"The only question I have left"*  Famous last words.  ;)  But in any case, SO works best as 'one question per post'.  If you have another question, start a new thread.  *"can't figure out how to add the example"*  There should be an 'edit' button below the question.  Don't put code into comments, it becomes unreadable.

Comment: BTW - `Applet` is also effectively an AWT component.  Use `JApplet` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Don't mix Swing and AWT components together.** Use all Swing components.  Mixing Swing and AWT components causes many problems.
2. Call `validate()` after adding all components.  That tells the JVM to validate the layout of the components.  It is part of what `pack()` does for a frame.
3. Use a `CardLayout` for swapping between the different GUI elements.